# jQuery attr() not working while dynamically updating it

Tags: jquery

I am having trouble with jQuery attr(). Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var Religion = $("#Religion"),
        Hindu = $("#Hindu"), 
        Muslim = $("#Muslim"), 
        Christian = $("#Christian");

    Religion.change(function(){ 
        var sReligion = $(this).val();  

        if(sReligion=="1") {
            SelectCaste.css('display','none');
            Hindu.css('display','block');
            Hindu.attr('name','Caste');
            Muslim.css('display','none');
            Muslim.attr('name','');
            Christian.css('display','none');
            Christian.attr('name','');
        }
        else if(sReligion=="2") {
            Hindu.css('display','none');
            Hindu.attr('name','');
            Muslim.css('display','block');
            Muslim.attr('name','Caste');
            Christian.css('display','none');
            Christian.attr('name','');
        }
        else if(sReligion=="3") {
            Hindu.css('display','none');
            Hindu.attr('name','');
            Muslim.css('display','none');
            Muslim.attr('name','');
            Christian.css('display','block');
            Christian.attr('name','Caste');
        }
    });
});
```

If sReligion (actually a select box) value is set to '1', then the attribute is set for Hindu. i.e., 
`<select name='Caste' id="Hindu"><option value=''>Select Caste</option>...</select>`

But if i change the sReligion value, other than '1', then the attribute is not set and name=" ",  for other conditions.

Kindly suggest me a good solution..

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What are you trying to do? I'm pretty sure you can accomplish the same thing without changing names and all that.

Comment: Also, for hiding, why not just use Hindo.hide(); instead of Hindu.css('display', 'none');

Comment: what is `SelectCaste.css('display','none');` ?

Comment: ... no no no, that is not a neat code. Drop us some HTML and we'll try to help you! Try to use [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) if possible

Comment: Why use numeric values for your select options? You could have made this **so** much easier on yourself by using `<option value="Hindu">Hindu</option>`

Comment: Please edit your question to provide additional information. Answers are reserved for solutions to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Simply make 3 selects with 3 different names, and on your back end use the appropriate one depending on the Religion value.

Also, you can simply use show/hide from jquery:

```
   if(sReligion=="1") {
        Hindu.show();
        Muslim.hide();
        Christian.hide();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is working fine. The problem was with the Firebug HTML console !!! It does not update the code dynamically. For every change in the selebox, i have to close and again open the firebug console to see the updated code.

Thanks to Mohamed Nuur and meagar for your timely help...

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to have one drop down based on what was selected, it would be better to have one `select` that is the visible one, and the rest are hidden, but you only use their content.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var Religion = $("#Religion"),
        Hindu = $("#Hindu"), 
        Muslim = $("#Muslim"), 
        Christian = $("#Christian");

    Religion.change(function(){ 
        var sReligion = $(this).val();  

        if(sReligion=="1") {
            // copy Hindu to  select caste
        } else if(sReligion=="2") {
            // copy Muslim to select caste
        } else if(sReligion=="3") {
            // copy Christian to select caste
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide HTML, I have supplied a sample implementation. I also cleaned up your code. The main fix was to apply the change() function to the jquery selector, instead of to the Religion variable:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var SelectCaste = $("#SelectCaste");
                var Religion = $("#Religion"),
                    Hindu = $("#Hindu"),
                    Muslim = $("#Muslim"),
                    Christian = $("#Christian");

                $("#Religion").change(function(){
                    Hindu.hide().attr('name', '');
                    Muslim.hide().attr('name', '');
                    Christian.hide().attr('name', '');

                    var sReligion = $(this).val();

                    if(sReligion=="1") {
                        SelectCaste.hide();
                        Hindu.show();
                        Hindu.attr('name','Caste');
                    }
                    else if(sReligion=="2") {
                        Muslim.show();
                        Muslim.attr('name','Caste');
                    }
                    else if(sReligion=="3") {
                        Christian.show();
                        Christian.attr('name','Caste');
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="SelectCaste">
            <select id="Religion">
                <option>- Select One -</option>
                <option value="1">Hindu</option>
                <option value="2">Muslim</option>
                <option value="3">Christian</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id="Hindu">Hindu</div>
        <div id="Muslim">Muslim</div>
        <div id="Christian">Christian</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, I should have caught that. Each of the dual statements in the if statement bodies should be chained.